# Around(:each) overriding before(:each)

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am doing some stunts using around each. I found some different odd with `around(:each)`. When I run below example it gives output as:

```
describe "AroundSpec" do
  before(:each) do
    p "On before each block"
  end

  around(:each) do
    p "On around each block"
  end

  it "1+1 = 2" do
    expect(1+1).to eq(2)
  end
end
```

output:

```
  "On around each block"
 .

  Finished in 0.00038 seconds
  1 example, 0 failures
```

If you notice it doesn't executing before each block. Is this way suppose to be it work or is it a bug in rspec? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `around(:each)` wrong I think. In order to do this properly, you have to pass your test into the block as an argument. When you run this test:

```
around(:each) do | example |
    p "Before the test"
    example.run
    p "After the test"
end
```

The output of your test file using this code would be:

```
"Before the test"
"On before each block"
"After the test"
```

What your code is doing is ignoring the `before` block and just executing your `around` (the `1+1=2` test is never actually run). The documentation for this can be found here:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Hooks#around-instance_method

Comment: Can you accept the answer as correct if it worked please? (click the tick under the downvote button)